# Git repo: Unravelling my mess into tidy branches

Tags: git, branch

I wanted to play with a project, so git cloned it and, following its instructions, created a local branch for my configuration (I guess so that users can merge updates back).

At first I was just tweaking to suit my preferences, so I didn't bother with any further branching, but now I have some code that might be useful to someone else, but with my passwords, etc in the same branch.

Effectively, I have one big branch from which I'd like to have:

- Postgres backend (default) but with some new code I've added
- MySQL backend (the biggest change I've made) with that same new code
- <strike>My settings: I can't git ignore the settings file because I occasionally have to add sections for new functionality, but I need to keep my personal settings out of the public branches! I guess this would work best as a local-only branch.</strike> *Ok. Fixed this. But the main problem remains.*
- Dev branches, which I would branch from the MySQL.

Starting from scratch, I think I could figure out how to branch/merge the various updates, but is there an **easy** way to walk through the existing repo and choose which commits to apply to which branch? Or possibly create a branch from a point upstream then merge back, excluding certain commits?

Comment: What are the passwords for? If they're for something like a local database it dosn't really matter if you leave it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I bit the bullet. In short:

1. Copy the whole repo and working directory to a backup directory
2. In that backup directory, with my the latest branch selected, use "git log -p" t0 find the first commit to get rid of.
3. git rebase -i ~1
4. Change "pick" to "e" ("edit") in the editor, or remove the line to clear the whole commit
5. Follow instructions to remove any unwanted data from the commits.
6. Swap the backup and main directories.
7. Now, with the shiny new working directory, create any needed branches, taking the required files from elsewhere in your repo, or from your new backup directory.

Hopefully this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hung up on the "put my password in source control" comment.  Here are some ideas to avoid doing this, in decreasing order of preference:

1. If your program does not absolutely need a password for the most basic functionality, store it in a password manager (e.g. KeePassX) and cut and paste it into your live running program on start-up.
2. Store it as an environment variable on the server and have your program read it in.  Every OS has environment variables, and this lets you have a different password on every server.
3. Use strong public key cryptography.  Generate public and private keys for yourself and for the application.  Encrypt your password with your private key and the app's public key so that only the apps private key can decrypt it.  Then have the project maintainer do something secure with the app's private key (but give it to them without sending it through email or source control unless it is securely encrypted).  This way, you and your app have your password and without the app's private key, no one else can get it.
4. If none of the above are possible, you can do #2 with a flat file and manually fill in the password when you install.
5. If all of the above are too much work, you probably don't have a secure application.  Consider doing away with the password altogether and making public whatever it is you were protecting.

Comment: Well the passwords are for a) the database and b) to identify on IRC. So they're not super-secure passwords, just not ones I want out in public. 
They're already in a separate .cfg file, but when the structure of that file needs changing, the updates need to be commited. So, as I see it, a little local branch could still pull down all the structural changes.
I guess the alternative would be to only commit the template file, but that means changing it back manually every time I make a change. And again, the passwords involved really aren't *that* important.

Comment: On reflection, maybe the best solution is to git ignore the cfg and update a template instead. It'll be easier to apply the changes to the template than to apply my config to the real cfg